# Make sure that string is key interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this

```
interface Cat {
    color: string,
    weight: number,
    cute: Boolean, // eventhough all cats are cute!
}
```

Now, I have to do something like this

```
const kitten: Cat = ...
Object.keys(kitten).some(prop => ['weight', 'color'].includes(prop)
```

Is there a way to make sure, that the strings passed to the `array` (`['weight', 'color']`) are part of the `interface` `Cat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arr: (keyof Cat)[] = ["weight", "color"]
Object.keys(kitten).some(prop => arr.includes(prop)
```

or for typescript 4.9 or higher

```
Object.keys(kitten).some(prop => (['weight', 'color'] satisfies (keyof Cat)[]).includes(prop))
```

to bypass `Object.keys` error.

```
type ObjectKeys<T> = (keyof T)[];
(Object.keys(kitten) as ObjectKeys<Cat>).some(prop => (['weight', 'color'] satisfies (keyof Cat)[]).includes(prop))
```

Comment: This hightlights `prop` in `includes(prop)` and says `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"weight" | "color"'.`

Comment: That happens because Object.keys works a bit weird. I will update my anwser